# Save all images in ListView

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, vk

I am loading a bunch of images from Vk.com in a ListView.I'd like to be able to download/save all images in any list to the phone's gallery, either in a simple event or by default. How would I go about this?
This is the XAML.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton FontSize="15" FontFamily="Times New Roman" Icon="Back" Label="Albums" Click="AppBarButton_Click"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"> </RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" FontSize="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
    <ListView  Grid.Row="1"
               ItemsSource="{Binding}"
               SelectionMode="None"
              IsItemClickEnabled="False"
               >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                    <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"  Source="{Binding image_final}"
                           AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"
                           Width="Auto"
                           Height="Auto"
                           ></Image>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

     </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Have edited the question.Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged this as WP8 and WP8.1. The code below is for 8, however shouldn't take too much work for 8.1.

You can download and save an image to the users gallery like this:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.IO;

  WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, ev) =>
                    {
                        var streamResourceInfo = new StreamResourceInfo(ev.Result, null);

                        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                        bitmap.SetSource(streamResourceInfo.Stream);
                        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

                        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
                        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            Extensions.SaveJpeg(bmp, stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                            library.SavePicture("imagename.jpg", stream.ToArray());
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("The picture has been saved to your Pictures Hub", "Success!", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                    };

                client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/imageurl.jpg"));
```

Obviously put the correct image URL in the last line. And optionally replace `"imagename.jpg"` with the real name of the image.

Answer (score 0):

This link really explains everything: saving images, and organizing them into folders. Definitely worth a read.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/769c9a6c-961c-47ea-bddf-a381db932289/saving-an-image-from-the-web-to-the-saved-pictures-folder-in-windows-phone-81-rt-c?forum=wpdevelop

Explanation:

```
//Create a storage folder in the Pictures Library:

StorageFolder AppFolder = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFolderAsync("XYZ", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

//Naming and storing the file:

var uri = imageuri; //image uri
var filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);   //designates file name
var thumbnail = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri);
var remoteFile = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(filename, uri, thumbnail);
await remoteFile.CopyAsync(albumname, filename, NameCollisionOption.FailIfExists); //Fail if argument filename is a string by which a file is already saved.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Say you're a busy developer who needs an answer to a question. You find this question on StackOverflow which matches yours exactly. Would you follow some link that somebody posted, claiming it's 'definitely worth a read', or would you keep scrolling and look for an answer where all the information is already in the answer? What if the link goes dead? What if you're at a really strict workplace where 'social' being in the url is blocked? Please edit your answer to include all the relevant information. Many thanks.

Comment: OP has brought in the substance of the link according to the suggestions in the comments. I am voting to retain it.